# select custom number of datas from sql table using datagrid input

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

in my c#.net application i will send dataname and noofcopies to sql using datagrid.From sql return the data in the format of which i mentioned below.

in datagrid:

```
data1 - 4copies
data2 - 3copies
data3 - 2copies
```

then the result should be

```
data1
data1
data1
data1
data2
data2
data2
data3
data3
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
declare @Stuff as Table ( Name VarChar(10), Number Int )
insert into @Stuff ( Name, Number ) values ( 'data1', 4 ), ( 'data2', 3 ), ( 'data3', 2 )

; with Repeat ( Name, Number, Counter ) as (
  select Name, Number, 1
    from @Stuff
    where Number > 0
  union all
  select Name, Number, Counter + 1
    from Repeat
    where Counter < Number
  )
select Name
  from Repeat
  order by Name, Counter
  option ( maxrecursion 0 )
```

Here, the 'Number' column of @Stuff is the no of copies.....